# LINQPad "native" connection to local Windows Search/oledb database

Tags: oledb, linqpad

I'm trying to use LINQPad to connect to my local Windows Search index. I'm able to connect manually using code as described here: https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/2060/connection-to-windows-search:

```cs
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection ("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\""))
{
    connection.Open();
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 10 System.ItemPathDisplay, System.ItemUrl FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE System.ItemType = '.config'";
    cmd.ExecuteReader().Dump();   // LINQPad lets you Dump a DataReader
}
```

I'm hoping that by now there's a way to do it using the native LINQPad connections. I played around a little with the 3rd-party "LINQ to DB" driver but haven't been successful. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that is possible with a naïve OleDB driver because the provider for WIndows Search doesn't implement the Schema features needed for generating the table definitions with columns. It also seems like it is not really SQL compatible since it is possible for items to have different columns depending on the Shell properties implemented by the document type being indexed. It might be possible to create a strongly typed assembly connection if you built an assembly describing Windows Search, though I couldn't quickly find a list of available Shell Properties.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage, it seems you are correct, Joe replied to my post here https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/comment/6739#Comment_6739, confirming there's not driver for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe Albahari (LINQPad creator) confirmed that there's no driver for this. Here's what I came up with instead, using the `Dapper` and `System.Data.OleDb` nuget packages:

```cs
const string defaultActivityQuery = @"SELECT
    System.ActivityHistory.AppId,
    System.ActivityHistory.AppActivityId,
    System.ActivityHistory.StartTime, 
    System.ActivityHistory.EndTime,
    System.ActivityHistory.ActiveDuration,
    System.Activity.AppDisplayName,
    System.Activity.ContentUri,
    System.Activity.Description,
    System.Activity.DisplayText,
    System.Activity.AppImageUri,
    System.Activity.BackgroundColor
FROM SystemIndex
WHERE (System.Activity.ActivityId IS NOT NULL) AND (System.ActivityHistory.StartTime > {0})
ORDER BY System.ActivityHistory.EndTime DESC";

...

var activities = WinSearch(string.Format(defaultActivityQuery, DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToFileTimeUtc()));
...

static List<ActivityRecord> WinSearch(string query)
{
    using OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"");

    var results = oleDbConnection.Query(query);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ActivityRecord>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results));
}

public class ActivityRecord
{
    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITYHISTORY.APPID")]
    public string? AppId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITYHISTORY.STARTTIME")]
    public string? StartTimeString
    {
        set => this.StartTime = double.TryParse(value, out double result) ? DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long)result).ToLocalTime() : null;
    }

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITYHISTORY.ENDTIME")]
    public string? EndTimeString
    {
        set => this.EndTime = double.TryParse(value, out double result) ? DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long)result).ToLocalTime() : null;
    }

    public DateTime? EndTime { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITYHISTORY.ActiveDuration")]
    public string? ActiveDurationString
    {
        set => this.ActiveDuration = double.TryParse(value, out double result) ? TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)result) : null;
    }

    public TimeSpan? ActiveDuration { get; private set; }

    public TimeSpan? Duration => this.EndTime - this.StartTime;

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITY.APPDISPLAYNAME")]
    public string? AppDisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITY.ContentUri")]
    public string? ContentUri { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITY.DESCRIPTION")]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITY.DISPLAYTEXT")]
    public string? DisplayText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.ACTIVITYHISTORY.APPACTIVITYID")]
    public string? AppActivityId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!